# Using Unix "find" to traverse a specific folder path

Tags: unix, find

I have a directory structure as follows

`/top-level`

`/top-level/1`, `/top-level/2`, ... `/top-level/nn`

`/top-level/xx/dir1`, `/top-level/xx/dir2`, `/top-level/xx/dir3`

Only `dir3` in each numbered branch holds files of interest. Ideally, I would like `find` to ONLY look at `dir3` and ignore any other directories at that level (there may be more than 2 to ignore). Presently, I'm using this line which works, but the execution time seems to indicate `find` is going into `dir1` and `dir2` and checking every file against `-path`, which is very time-consuming and pointless:

```
find /top-level -path '/top-level/[0-9]*/dir3/*.log' -type f -mtime +1 -print
```

I was trying to find a "conditional" that would only allow `dir3` to "pass", but couldn't find anything that only worked on the "directory level". I also tried finding a way to use `-prune` without having to have an enumerated list of folders NOT to search, but have not been able to come up with a syntax that works.

Any INFORMED thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows graphical concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: Please provide code to generate an example directory structure with (empty) files including those to be ignored and add the corresponding expected output. I suggest to look at `-mindepth` / `-maxdepth` and logical OR operation `-o`, e.g. `\( -name folder3 -o -prune \)`

Comment: Rob; yes am aware they are called "directories" in unix; was using folder as a matter of convenience, but changed for greater accuracy

Comment: Bodo; Not sure what a sample directory structure would provide for you that the description isn't already providing.

Comment: The creation of a sample directory sturcture means that all readers can quickly create your problem "space" and experiment. It also eliminates any chance that readers will be testing w an environment that doesn't really match your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use `-prune` to avoid descending into the non-`folder3` directories.

```
find /top-level \( ! -name folder3 -type d -prune \) -type f -mtime +1 -print
```

Comment: Chepner; thanks for responding. This doesn't appear to work; no files from folder3 are listed out. My understanding is that -name only looks at the BASE filename, removing any folder path items, so not sure how this would work.

Comment: Oh, right, let's make sure we only prune *folders* that don't match `folder3`.

Comment: exactly, but I'm wondering if \(! -path /top-level/[0-9]*/logs -prune\) will work

Comment: I guess what I looking for is the syntax to prune any directory != dir3. I tried ! -path but that doesn't do the right thing. I need some syntax for -path to return "false" if path != dir3